# How to relay incoming mail via postfix based on the domain sender

Tags: email, postfix, vps

I have a VPS(DHCP IP with port 25 forwarded to this serv) with postfix and I want to relay all incoming emails to other VPS with local IP, based on the domain.

Ex:

Mail1 incoming to xxxxx@example1.com - this should be relayed to vps with IP xxxx1 where domain example1.com is set

Mail2 incoming to yyyyy@example2.com - this should be relayed to vps with IP xxxx2  where domain example2.com is set

Mail3 incoming to zzzzz@example3.com - this should be relayed to vps with IP xxxx3  where domain example3.com is set

Is it possible?Or another approach to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, you may use the transport file, usually /etc/postfix/transport.

Specify domain and smtp gateway to relay, es.

example.com      :[ip_gateway_vps1]

(verify exact syntax with: man transport )

You may have to add

transport_maps =  hash:/etc/postfix/transport

in you main.cf file, and restart postfix.

Remember to convert file in postmap format:

postmap /etc/postfix/transport

and to reload postfix:

postfix reload